# Align Navbar Beside the Logo in Wordpress Storefront Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes, navbar

I'm trying to edit the Wordpress WooCommerce Theme Storefront.

I want to align the navbar to the right, beside the logo.

After reading some stackoverflow questions with similar answers, I've tried to change the display to inline from block for many elements, but with no results. (I am adding the edited code to the child theme's style.css)

I currently have something like this -> [Navbar below logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WkNW.png) and I want something like this ->
[Navbar beside logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTG4r.png)

Here is the CSS from the storefront theme that relates to the navigation of the theme.

```css
.primary-navigation {
    display: none;
}
.main-navigation:after, .main-navigation:before {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.main-navigation:after {
    clear: both;
}
.main-navigation div.menu {
    display: none;
}
.main-navigation div.menu:last-child {
    display: block;
}
.main-navigation .menu {
    clear: both;
}
.handheld-navigation, .main-navigation div.menu>ul:not(.nav-menu), .nav-menu {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all, ease, .8s;
    transition: all, ease, .8s;
}
.handheld-navigation {
    clear: both;
}
.handheld-navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
}
.main-navigation.toggled .handheld-navigation, .main-navigation.toggled .menu>ul:not(.nav-menu), .main-navigation.toggled ul[aria-expanded=true] {
    max-height: 1750px;
}
.main-navigation ul {
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.main-navigation ul ul {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 1.41575em;
}
.main-navigation ul li a {
    padding: .875em 0;
    display: block;
}
.main-navigation ul li a:hover {
    color: #e6e6e6;
}
.site-main nav.navigation {
    clear: both;
    padding: 2.617924em 0;
}
.site-main nav.navigation:after, .site-main nav.navigation:before {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.site-main nav.navigation:after {
    clear: both;
}
.site-main nav.navigation .nav-next a, .site-main nav.navigation .nav-previous a {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all, ease, .3s;
    transition: all, ease, .3s;
    padding: .6180469716em 1em;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.site-main nav.navigation .nav-previous {
    float: left;
    width: 50%}
.site-main nav.navigation .nav-previous a:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1em);
    -ms-transform: translate(-1em);
    transform: translate(-1em);
}
.site-main nav.navigation .nav-next {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%}
.site-main nav.navigation .nav-next a:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1em);
    -ms-transform: translate(1em);
    transform: translate(1em);
}
```

Thank You for the support.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing a working example of your HTML and CSS together, that show the issue.

Comment: My site is on local host. I don't know how exactly to show you. At www.alkalinecopperbottle.com I have an uploaded version which is a couple of days old, but I guess it is enough to solve this problem.

Comment: please edit your question with navbar HTML element. Example <nav>html html html<nav> or <div id="nav">html html html</div>.

Answer (score 1):

Update your functions.php file in your child theme with the following code. Please note this removes the cart, searchbar and secondary storefront navs so that the navigation links are in line with the logo.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'align_menu_right');

function align_menu_right() {
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_secondary_navigation', 30 );
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation', 50 );
    add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation', 30 );

    if ( function_exists( 'storefront_header_cart' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_cart', 60 );
    }
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_product_search', 40 );
}
```

And update your css with the below:

```
<style>
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        #masthead .col-full {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #masthead .main-navigation {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .woocommerce-active .site-header div.site-branding {
            width: auto;
        }
    }
</style>
```

This is based off of a [plugin](https://www.pootlepress.com/2019/05/align-menu-right-woocommerce-storefront-free-plugin/)